# To get an condition for excel mentioned in the attachment

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please follow the attachment and let me know how can i get true, false and NA condition for the excel sheet

Column A --> It has repeated set of ID's (A,B,C)
Column B --> Data 1 to be compared with Data 2. And if the data2 is anywhere present in Data 1 and both share the same data from column ReportID, I should get true...otherwise false...and if data2 is blank then NA

[image: sample data]

Comment: NA() will give the error.

Comment: leave NA....if i can get true/false....that's enough

Comment: So if() will return True or False if you don’t specify anything else.

Comment: i want the formula ...so that I can get the TRUE or FALSE....column D is the formula column...Do you have the formula ?

Comment: Well, check out if() and make an effort - I am on a smartphone so i can’t test, however given you hints.

Comment: I tried if() already, but now want some external help...anyone who can give me the formula...thanks anyways

Comment: So, IF(isblank(C2),NA(),further_test_with if) is a start

Comment: i want the main formula....till here i know

Comment: Everything I show you claim you know, so show what you have achieved so far then we will see what you need. Also you might consider match().

Comment: =IF(A7=A6,IF(OR(C7=B6,C7=B7,C7=B8,C7=B9,C7=B10),TRUE,FALSE) --> I tried this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4961700/solar-mike --> It would be better if you give me the formulae directly...i don't think this is something very critical for a person who has knowledge of excel....I don't have expertise on this....Apart from the formulae...you are giving me everything

Comment: it can be a great help if you directly give me the formulae.....if at all you have knowledge on it

Comment: `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A11&C2:C11,A2:A11&B2:B11,0))` (may require `ctrl+shift+enter`). Not sure why you want `NA` in case of empty, but then use Solar Mike's suggestion to wrap it in `IF(IS BLANK())`. Please respect people that try to help you. The less you share, the less we can help.

Comment: no this is wrong....i will explain again..in 1st column there are repetative data's ....so now suppose in column 1 there is data A, now for all the A data, column 3 data should be compared with column 2 data and if we found any equal case overthere i should get true

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use COUNTIFS:

[image]

Formula in column D:

```
=IF(C2="";"NA";COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11;A2;$B$2:$B$11;C2)>0)
```